# Is it possible in grafana to use one datasource query for several panels?

Tags: grafana

So, I have grafana, where my underlying database is AWS Timestream.
I have around 20 widgets (panes) in my dashboard, which makes 20 calls to the datasource.

AWS prices 10mb minimum per query, which causes me to pay 200mb worth of queries instead of few MB which is the amount of data scanned.

What I want to do, is to run the a unified query (take the 20 queries and run them once with outer joins), then perform the queries of the panes against this result.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can try reuse query result https://grafana.com/blog/2020/10/14/learn-grafana-share-query-results-between-panels-to-reduce-load-time/ and apply transformations.

Answer (score 0):

yes, in Grafana there is a special built-in datasource called `dashboard`. Select this option and you can re-use the query from another panel. Very useful for reducing the number of queries you make to a backend for more or less the same data. As Jan says, you can then use transformations to fiddle with the data:

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/